# Primefaces p:ajax listener conditional update

Tags: ajax, primefaces

JSF Page:

```
<p:commandButton>
  <p:ajax process="@this" update="name desc msg"
    listener="#{bean.deleteListener}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

Bean:

```
public void deleteListener() {
  if (data.size() == 0) {
    // updates only "msg"
    setMsg("There is no data to delete");
    return;
  }
  setMsg("Data deleted.");
  // and updates the bean values for "name" and "desc" also.
  ...
}
```

Is it possible to conditionally update for an ajax call based on ajax listener logic. I would like to update the client ids "name desc msg" conditionally as shown in the listener code below (note this is a sample scenario in a larger application). The application uses Primefaces 5. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, use the PrimeFaces RequestContext in your listener

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();

//update panel
context.update("form:panel");
```

**See also:**
 - http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/requestContext.xhtml