# <p:ajax update=""> inside nested components

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

Iam using Mojarra 2.2.11 (WildFly 9.0.1) with PF 5.3.

In relation with my original question:
[<p:ajax update="...> cell or row update inside PF subTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32289847/pajax-update-cell-or-row-update-inside-pf-subtable)

I am still struggling with the following line: `<p:ajax update=":tabView1:form1:mainTable".../>`

The following part has been changed: `#{subTableView.getAllheaders(tabview)}`. Below references have been used but the datatable refresh does not seem to work.

I have done several researches and tried multiple options without success.
The operation looks easy: I need to process a selectOneRadio value to update the outputLabel in the next column of the datatable. I am not getting any error: but the radio selection comes back to the initial position when another radio is clicked without updating the outputlabel.

1. I paid attention that outputLabel is surrounded by a panelGroup (see reference). NamingContainer with proper syntax has been tried:

   - BalusC ref: [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo)
2. I tried with `RequestContext#update("tabView1:form1:mainTable:panel")` with the below references:

   - [Primefaces p:ajax listener conditional update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093119/primefaces-pajax-listener-conditional-update)
   - [PF Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/requestContext.xhtml)
3. `<f:ajax execute="" render=""/>` has been tried

   - Reference: Mastering JSF 2.2 Book
4. I was thinking about the last jQuery option but I still think it is doable with JSF.

Thank you for your time.

```
<p:tabView id ="tabView1" value="#{bean.titles}" var="tabItem" >

   <p:tab id="tab1" title="#{tabItem}" >

     <h:form id="form1" >

   <p:dataTable  id="mainTable" value="#{subTableView.getAllHeaders(tabItem)}" var="head" > 

     <p:subTable id="subTable1" value="#{head.questions}" var="question" >  

        <f:facet name="header">
            #{head.name}
        </f:facet>

        <p:column id="questionColumn">
            #{question.question}            
        </p:column>

        <p:column id="radioColumn">

            <p:selectOneRadio id="mainSelect" value="#{question.select1}" >

                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="#{question.responseOfYes}" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="#{question.responseOfNo}" />

                    // here is my pain:
                <p:ajax update=":tabView1:form1:mainTable"  process="@this"

                 listener="#{subTableView.updateSecond(question.select1)}"/>

            </p:selectOneRadio>

        </p:column> 


        <p:column id="responseColumn">

            <h:panelGroup id="panel" >
                <h:outputLabel id="display1" value="#{question.select1}" />                 
            </h:panelGroup>

        </p:column>

    </p:subTable>

  </p:dataTable>    

  </h:form>

    </p:tab>

 </p:tabView>
```

Comment: Is the client ID of the table really `tabView1:form1:mainTable`? (you checked the generated HTML output on that as instructed?) You've there a dynamic tabview, not a static tabview, so its iteration index would also be prepended.

Comment: @BalusC: Iam not getting any referencing error: I suppose the ID is correct (not checked the HTML). prependId set to true or false for the TabView: not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156 clearly says to look in HTML output for real client ID.

Comment: it contains iteration index like :0:, :1: e.g.: `tabView1:1:form1:mainTable:0:subTable1:0:panel`. Not mentioned but also tried: `styleClass="myClass"` with `update="@(.myClass)"`

Comment: @BalusC: to make my table "traceable" would you suggest to use `<c:forEach>` OR to follow the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713718/how-to-make-a-grid-of-jsf-composite-component)? Thank you